# Preventing Multiple Submits Struts2: Not Showing Success Message

Tags: java, javascript, user-interface, struts2

I am trying to prevent multiple form submit in struts2. I am using tokenSession (TokenSessionStoreInterceptor). As per its behavior it considers only first request and ignores the subsequent submits. The problem here is that it after successful completion of request it doesn't show the action message. for eg if order creation is successful it goes to the proper view but does not displays any message like the order is created which it does in normal scenarios. Any pointers?

Here is my config:

```
<action name="createOrder"
        class="com.example.OrdersAction" method="createOrder">
        <interceptor-ref name="storeStack" /> 
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
            <param name="includeMethods">createOrder</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="tiles" name="input">createOrders</result>
        <result type="tiles" name="error">createOrders</result>
        <result name="create" type="redirectAction">order</result>
        <result name="createAndAdd" type="redirectAction">

         </result>
    </action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of your interceptors.

```
<action name="createOrder" class="com.example.OrdersAction" method="createOrder">
        <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession">
            <param name="includeMethods">createOrder</param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="storeStack" /> 
        <result type="tiles" name="input">createOrders</result>
        <result type="tiles" name="error">createOrders</result>
        <result name="create" type="redirectAction">order</result>
        <result name="createAndAdd" type="redirectAction"></result>
</action>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I also tried that, this solution seems to work when while debugging the code, I mean the actionmessages were persisting across the actions.But in the normal mode it was not working.

Comment: Why would this have worked... i have a similar problem, but i'm just wondering why you would want tokenSession to execute at the top of the stack, and not the bottom.